# svg use in React

Tags: reactjs, svg, react-hooks, converters

I am trying to show svg response in my react app.
I am fetching the data from an api and in response I am getting a svg I am trying to this in my app but it just displaying as a string what should I do to make it look more like svg.
Here I am Fetchig the data from an api.

```
 const useChartFetch = (url, submited) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchChart = async() => {
        const res = await fetch(url)
        const data = await res.text();

        setData(data)
    }
    fetchChart();
  }, [submited]);

  return [data];
};

export default useChartFetch;
```

This is where i am trying to show my svg response.

```
const ShowKundli = ({userData, submited}) => {

    const [chart] = useChartFetch(`https://api.vedicastroapi.com/v3-json/horoscope/chart-image?dob=${userData.dob}&tob=${userData.tob}&lat=${userData.lat}&lon=${userData.lng}&tz=5.5&div=D1&color=%23ff3366&style=north&api_key=c932d1d9-9d8b-5e22-9949-abec233387c9&lang=en`, submited);
    
  return (
    <div className=' bg-black text-white'>
        
            <div className=' mt-10 text-center flex justify-center'> 
                <h1 className='text-left text-6xl font-bold mb-10'>Chart</h1>
               {chart}
            </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: If your wanting to convert the text string into HTML / SVG, you can use [dangerouslySetInnerHtml](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml). Its not recommended though due to cross site scripting. If you can I would load the file as an image / svg and include it that way.

Comment: ` ` `
<div className='bg-amber-500 h-fit w-fit mx-auto' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: chart }}/>
` ` `

I am using this for now but it is not the ideal solution for me.